# Whats best for filling core data database?

Tags: ios, database, core-data

I'm playing around with ideas and want to create an app with a large database. I understand the most efficient way to do this is to load the data into core data and then grab whatever I need from there.

However I haven't used databases in an app before - whats the most efficient way to fill that core data database?

Most of the data will be stored on the phone - xml, plist, other? and some on a server?

Whats best for prep populating core data from within the app and externally?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you would benefit from looking over some tutorials and when you have specific questions post them. Here's one tutorial [Core Data on iOS 5 Tutorial: Getting Started](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started) Apple also has good docs + WWDC videos on Core Data vs sqlite vs plist.